# Word macro to remove bottom border from each row

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'd like to create a macro that loops through each row in a table and removes the bottom border.

So far I have:

```
Sub Remove()

Set myTable = Selection.Tables(1)
    With myTable.Borders

Selection.Cells.Borders(wdBorderBottom) = wdLineStyleNone

    End With

End Sub
```

But it only works for one row and it has to be selected.
How to apply it to all rows?

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through all rows in your table, and format each row bottom border to `wdLineStyleNone`.

**Code**

Try the code below:

```
Sub Remove()

Dim myTable As Table
Dim r As Variant

Set myTable = ThisDocument.Tables(1)

For Each r In myTable.Rows ' <-- loop through all rows in table
    r.Borders(wdBorderBottom) = wdLineStyleNone
Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It looks good, but when I try it,
then a message is displayed:

Run-time error '5941':
The requested member of the collection does not exist

and "Set myTable = ThisDocument.Tables(1)" gets highlighted.

Should the script select the table first?
I tried adding "ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Select" but it didn't help.

Comment: @LeFunk there is no need to select a table, do you have 1 table created in your Word document ? where this code lies ?

Comment: I have a document with just one table and it has one column.
The code is in the usual macros window (if that's the correct term).