# Changing Visible Word borders via VBA from 1/2pt to 3/4pt

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm very new to VBA. I review reports in MS Word from my co-workers on a daily basis and need to make sure that all instances of table borders of 1/2pt be converted to 3/4pt.

There are also instances of thicker border weights up to 1 1/2pt. But I only need to make sure that the minimum weight is 3/4pt.

This is my code so far (that I modified from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42324864/16766294)) but it applies the weight to ALL BORDERS and only seems to work for one table in each document.

```
Sub BorderWeight()

Dim myTable As Table
Dim r As Variant

Set myTable = ThisDocument.Tables(1)

For Each r In myTable.Rows ' <-- loop through all rows in table
    r.Borders(wdBorderBottom) = wdLineWidth075pt
Next r

End Sub
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your code need a second loop around the `For Each r... Next r` to check all the Tables (a `For Each myTable in ThisDocument.Tables... Next myTable`), and then you need a `If` condition to check if the line width need to be modified of not. BTW you say the code apply to all borders but to me it seems it should apply only to bottom borders given the code you posted.

Comment: Thanks @VincentG! I get where you're going with this but I can't quite translate it to proper code. Can you steer me to the right direction?

`Dim myTable As Table
Dim r As Variant

Set myTable = ThisDocument.Tables(1)

For Each r In myTable.Rows ' <-- loop through all rows in table
    r.Borders(wdBorderBottom) = wdLineWidth075pt
    
    For Each myTable In This.Document.Tables 'ERROR HERE
        If r.Borders(wdBorderBottom) = wdLineWidth050pt Then
        Set r.Borders(wdBorderBottom) = wdLineWidth075pt
        End If
    Next myTable

Next r



End Sub`

Comment: The `For each myTable in ThisDocument.Tables` should replace the `Set myTable = ThisDocument.Tables(1)`, not inside the r loop.